# How to get the right Validation exception in django-rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I want to catch an exception from django-rest-auth. The class rest_auth.serializers.LoginSerializer throws various exceptions, all exceptions.ValidationError

```
msg = _('Must include "email" and "password".')
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)

 msg = _('Must include "username" and "password".')
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)

raise serializers.ValidationError(_('E-mail is not verified.'))
```

I am only interested in handling the last one 'E-mail is not verified.' but a try block will catch all ValidationError exceptions. How can I handle only the one that interests me given that the string is also translated? would a check like this be ok or there is a better way?

```
if exc.data is _('E-mail is not verified.')
    # do stuff
    raise exc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling exceptions based on the Validation Error message might be a bit of an anti-pattern, and you might regret going down that road. One way around this is to check the conditions that raise the exceptions - before it becomes in an exception.

I don't have any details of your app, but another option would be to override the 'validate' method in rest_auth serializer. This would allow you to check the for the condition first (before rest_auth) and handle it however you want. The nice thing about this projects is that they are open source, and you can [view the source](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/serializers.py#L103) to see how it raises this error.

```
class SpecialValidator(LoginSerializer):
   def validate(self, attrs):
       username = attrs.get('username')
       email_address = user.emailaddress_set.get(email=user.email)
       if not email_address.verified:
           # This is where you put in your special handling
       return super(SpecialValidator, self).validate(attrs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did consider sub classing the LoginSerializer class and override the validate method. My main concern was that the validate method has many lines of code which I had to copy to my override and by doing that I would essentially create a fork that would not benefit from later improvements. But your suggestion does seem simpler.